# ClassCastException while following Decorator pattern

Tags: java, oop, exception, casting, decorator

I'm learning to use Decorator pattern in some combination with Template method in Java. I have a compilation error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class Room cannot be cast to class Flat (Room and Flat are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

but I have no idea why it happens and how to correct it.
In a nutshell, my program has to calculate area of a flat adding areas of its rooms and customers can add flats to their basket. So I've created an abstract class Premise for Flats and Rooms as well.

```
public abstract class Premise {
    protected double dwellingArea;
    protected double totalArea;
    public String getInfo(){ return "Rooms: "; }
    public abstract double getDwellingArea();
    public abstract double getTotalArea();
}
```

I also have an abstract class Decorator.

```
public abstract class Decorator extends Premise {
    public abstract String getInfo();
    Decorator(double totalArea){
        this.totalArea=totalArea;
    }
}
```

After that I created class Flat that extends class Premise.

```
public class Flat extends Premise{
    private int floor;
    private double price;
    private String description;
    public int getFloor() {
        return floor;
    }
    public void setFloor(int floor) {
        this.floor = floor;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public Flat(int floor, double price, String description) {
        super();
        this.floor = floor;
        this.price = price;
        this.description=description;
    }
    @Override
    public double getDwellingArea() {
        return dwellingArea;
    }
    @Override
    public double getTotalArea() {
        return totalArea;
    }
}
```

Class Room extends Decorator.

```
public class Room extends Decorator{
    boolean isService;
    Premise apartment;

    @Override
    public String getInfo() {
        if(isService) {
            return apartment.getInfo()+" "+"service room ";
        }
        else {
            return apartment.getInfo()+" "+"dwelling room ";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public double getDwellingArea() {
        return apartment.dwellingArea+this.dwellingArea;
    }

    @Override
    public double getTotalArea() {
        return apartment.totalArea+this.totalArea;
    }

    Room(double totalArea, boolean isService, Premise apartment) {
        super(totalArea);
        this.isService=isService;
        if(isService=true) {
            dwellingArea=0;
        }
        else {
            dwellingArea=totalArea;
        }
        this.apartment=apartment;
    }
}
```

Also I have an abstract class User for both customers and realtors.

```
public abstract class User {
    protected String name;
    protected String phone;
    protected String email;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public User(String name, String phone, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
    }
    public abstract void showList();
}
```

In class Customer there is an array list of selected flats.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Customer extends User{
    private ArrayList<Flat> flats;
    public Customer(String name, String phone, String email) {
        super(name, phone, email);
        flats=new ArrayList<Flat>();
    }
    @Override
    public void showList() {
        System.out.println("Customer "+name+" selected "+flats.size()+" apartments:");
        for(Flat flat:flats) {
            System.out.println(flat.getDescription());
        }
        
    }
    public void addFlat(Flat flat) {
        flats.add(flat);
    }
}
```

In class Main I'm trying to create flat and its room and a customer and later add the flat to the customer's list but it gives me the mistake that I mentioned above.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Premise flat1 = new Flat(5,25000,"A flat in a big city");
        flat1 = new Room(15, true, (Flat)flat1);
        Flat flat2 = new Flat(10,45000,"A flat in a large city"); 
        Customer client1 = new Customer("Jane Peterson","0950297789","jane@gmail.com"); 
        client1.addFlat((Flat)flat1); 
        client1.addFlat(flat2); 
    }

}
```

I will be extremely grateful if you told me why it goes like this and how to tackle the issue.

Comment: **Caution:** `if(isService=true)` is not doing what you want.  You’re not *checking* the value of isService, you’re *unconditionally setting it.*  You can avoid this mistake in the future by simply writing `if (isService)`.  There is never a reason to compare a boolean value to true.

Answer (score 1):

A `Room` is a `Decorator` is a `Premise`. But it's not a `Flat`. (The `Room` you create in line 8 has a `Flat` as it's `Premise apartment` member, but that doesn't make it a `Flat`!)

As for fixing this... You'd have to find a way to move the `getDescription()` method to the `Premise` class. That way, your `Customer` could have a `List<Premise>` instead of a `ArrayList<Flat>`. Replace the `addFlat(Flat flat)` method with `addPremise(Premise premise)` and remove the cast to `Flat` when you call the new method in `main()`.

btw: Why do you think the Decorator Pattern is a good way to model this? What does a Room decorating another Premise even mean? Isn't a Room (if rented separately) just another Premise?

Comment: Thank you! But when I change replace getDescription() with getInfo(), which is present at class Premise, it throws the same error.

Comment: See my edit above.